# Processing a file and targeting specific lines

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out the best way of achieving something but getting a bit lost.  So I need to read a log file and process its contents.  However, it is only specific content I want.

So the code I have so far is pretty straight forward, opens the file and prints out each line

```
public function handle()
{
    $file = fopen(storage_path('logs') . '/log.log', 'r');

    while(!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgets($file);
        print_r($line);
    }

    fclose($file);
}
```

So the output contains a lot of information basically, but on some lines, there will be an Object

```
[2021-07-22 18:14:01] local.INFO: Some info
[2021-07-22 18:14:01] local.INFO: "{\"somedata\":\"123\",\"something else\":123,\, \"body\":No,\}"
[2021-07-22 18:14:01] local.INFO: Some request
[2021-07-22 18:14:01] local.INFO: Some post
[2021-07-22 18:14:01] local.INFO: etc
[2021-07-22 18:14:01] local.INFO: etc
[2021-07-22 18:14:01] local.INFO: etc
[2021-07-22 18:14:01] local.INFO: etc
[2021-07-22 18:14:01] local.INFO: "{\"somedata\":\"234\",\"something else\":234,\, \"body\":Yes,\}"
```

So you can see that the second line above and the last line has and Object.  So what I am trying to do is get all the Objects from the file and perhaps put them in an array or something.

Would I use a regex or something for this?

My overall goal is the only obtain Objects with a body that has the value Yes, but perhaps it is best to extract all Objects first before processing them?

Any information appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex to solve this.

```
$pattern = '#^\\[([^\\]]+)\\] [^:]+: (.+)$#';

// enter loop
preg_match($pattern, $line, $matches);
$logMsg = $matches[2];
if (strpos($logMsg, '"{') === 0) {
  // this line contains json string
}
```

You can even get the log time with `$matches[1]` if you need it.

Comment: Thanks, the only issue I see is that wont this assume that the JSON is always at position 2 in the matched array?

Comment: The `$matches` array contains the full match in 0, which would be the entire line, then the matching groups in subsequent indexes. I've put the message in the second group, so it will always be in position 2 in matched lines. I suppose you can check the result from preg_match to see if the line is valid, but log messages shouldn't contain new lines, so as it stands this block of code assumes only valid log lines. It also assumes that `local` is a hostname or address, and it will never contain a colon, so no IPv6 addresses.